# Does iTunes in the Cloud apply to Movie Rentals?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, ios, itunes-store

I rented a movie from iTunes on my Mac running OS X 10.8. I was under the assumption that it would be available on my iPhone (iOS 6) and iPad (iOS 6) to stream or download but it isn't. It doesn't appear in the Videos app and I can't find it under Purchased in the iTunes Store on my devices. All of my devices are logged in under the same account.

Are iTunes movie rentals not available in the cloud? I know movie purchases are.

Every support document I found on Apple's website didn't mention rentals, only purchases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes movie rentals originally purchased on a computer can be moved between devices as many times as you like during the rental period but can only "exist" on one device at a time. To move it between devices, use iTunes with the device you want to put it on. See this [Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1390). Steps are:

1. Connect the device and select it in iTunes.
2. Click the Movies button.
3. Select the movie, and then click Move.
4. After all movies have been moved, click Apply in the lower-right corner of iTunes.

To answer your direct question: no, rentals do not currently exist in the cloud.

Answer (score -1):

You can't rent on a mac and then start looking at it on Apple tv and later finish watching it on another device (including the Mac). I spent 4 hrs on hold and 4 contacts at apple care and eventually got this answer. If someone can say for sure this is not rte. I would like to know.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, given that you can watch it as often as you want within the 24 hour rental period (48 hours outside the US) from when you first start watching it. If you **rent it** on an AppleTV, you cannot watch it on any other device, per the support article linked from my answer.